# What does this piece of code mean when setting state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
this.setState({
      object1: { ...object2 },
});
```

I know it does something to the state. but I'm not able to understand what it means? Is this a technique in JS/React?

Comment: 1. It uses setState the update the current state variable `object1` 2. Three dots also called as spread operator in es6, extracts everything from object2 here and put it in new object

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially setting `object1` to be the same as `object2` via [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax). For example:

```
this.state = { object1: { hello: 'world' } };

const object2 = { foo: 'bar' };

this.setState({ object1: { ...object2 } });
```

this would result in the state to be:

```
{ object1: { foo: 'bar' };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is spread operator and you can read more about it here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

The setState in your code is updating the current state variable object1 with the values from object2